# How to draw circle or rectangle on google maps

Tags: google-maps, iframe, maps

i want to draw circle or rectangle when i search somewhere on google maps. How to do this with iframe ? Is there any program or tool or something do this ?

Comment: javascript or android ??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Please post the code you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
// Instantiates a new CircleOptions object and defines the center and radius
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
.center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1))
.radius(1000)); // In meters

// Get back the mutable Circle
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```